# Tools that help building XML layouts for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to build up android app layout and my problem is that one element has some weird padding/margin and I can't find where it's been given. I triple checked my code and I'm sure that elements in my XML layout have no specific margins or padding (images attached). Is there any way to figure out what is going on? I have turned on show element borders on my device and it wasn't very helpful. I'm a beginner in the Android world and I wonder is there any specific tool to help in this kind of situation? I would be grateful for any kind of advice. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/monthPageTitlePageIndicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/historyViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="AAAAAA" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The red line below shows the unwanted space:

[image: Red line is unwanted space]

The following shows the borders:

[image: Borders shown]

Comment: Please post your XML.

Comment: I have add XML. I loading other views to ViewPager (those squares).